# Is there a way to create a generic approach to reduce amount of code for similar operations on state?

Tags: reactjs, dry

I am a beginner in JS/React/Redux. Is there a dynamic/parametric approach to call similar methods with parameters instead of repeating code?

```js
resetSelectedState() {
    const geoElement = Object.assign([], this.state.states); // create new copy to avoid mutation
    geoElement.forEach((a) => a.isSelected = false);
    this.setState({ states: geoElement });
}

resetSelectedCountry() {
    const geoElement = Object.assign([], this.state.countries); // create new copy to avoid mutation
    geoElement.forEach((a) => a.isSelected = false);
    this.setState({ countries: geoElement });
}

resetSelectedContinent() {
    const geoElement = Object.assign([], this.state.continents); // create new copy to avoid mutation
    geoElement.forEach((a) => a.isSelected = false);
    this.setState({ continents: geoElement });
}
```

In C# I would use a generic method with out type object to set that, but I am wondering if that is possible in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  Since the only difference is the object you're accessing in state, you can just pass that in and then DRY out your code.

```
doSomething(type) {
    const geoElement = Object.assign([], this.state[type]); // create new copy to avoid mutation
    geoElement.forEach((a) => a.isSelected = false);
    this.setState({ [type]: geoElement });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. it looks like [type] makes a life lot easier

Answer (score 2):

I would have a common method that will iterate and set and use the `computed property name` to avoid duplication.

```
resetSelectedState() {
    this.reset('states');
} 

resetSelectedCountry() {
  this.reset('countries');
}

resetSelectedContinent() {
  this.reset('continents');
}

reset(property) {
  const geoElement = [...this.state[property]];
    geoElement.forEach((a) => a.isSelected = false);

  this.setState({
    [property]: geoElement
  });
}
```